# Finding the range of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the range of $y=\tan \theta$ for $0<\theta<90$.

I drew the function out, and see that the function will be between $\tan 0 < y < \tan90$ but $\tan 90$ is undefined so what would the range be?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know $\tan0=?$ and $\tan90^\circ=?$ and $\frac{d(\tan\theta)}{d\theta}=\sec^2\theta>0\implies \tan\theta$ is always an increasing function

Comment: the range is $(0,+\infty)$. As $\theta$ approaches $90$, $tan(\theta)$ gets larger and larger without bound.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $\tan 0 = 0$ and $\tan 90$ = undefined?

Comment: what if the question was for $0 \le \theta \le 90$

Comment: Then it would be a bad question. As you said, $\tan\theta$ is undefined at $\theta = 90$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese oh okay, so is my book correct for saying y can take the value of all positive real numbers?

If I the question was $0 \le \theta \le 90$, how would you answer the question? What would you say?

Comment: If $0 < \theta < 90$, then yes. If the question is about $0 \leq \theta < 90$, then it is all non-negative real numbers. I don't know what they would want from you if $\theta = 90$ is included in the domain. You can extend $\tan$ to a function which maps into the extended real numbers, but I'm not sure that this is what is wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of $y = \tan \theta$ for $0 \lt \theta \lt 90^\circ$ is the set of all positive real numbers:
i.e., the range is all of the open interval $(0, + \infty)$.

Below is the graph of $y = \tan \theta$ where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2 = 90^\circ$ (source: Wolfram Alpha). Graphs always help to develop intuition regarding the range of functions, particularly trigonometric functions. We see that as $\theta$ increases and approaches $\pi/2$ radians $= 90^\circ$, $y = \tan\theta$ will grow without bound.

[image]

[image]

You can also ask WolframAlpha for the range directly and even restrict to a specified domain as in [range of tan(x) restricted to 0<=x<90 degrees](http://goo.gl/XBWkMV):

[image]